# is there a Python program using flask to use post method from a json

Tags: python, post, flask, postman, flask-restful

I have a json declared in my code. I want my json to be printed in postman once I hit that parameters.

EX:

```
Json = {
    "array": [
        {
            "ques": "1",
            "resp": {
                "ans": "anssssssssss",
                "syn": [
                    "sugg 1",
                    "sugg 2",
                    "sugg 3"
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "ques": "2",
            "resp": {
                "ans": "lijvmlooisj",
                "syn": [
                    "sugg 1",
                    "sugg 2",
                    "sugg 3"
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "ques": "3",
            "resp": {
                "ans": "hhhsdvkmoisi",
                "syn": [
                    "sugg 1",
                    "sugg 2",
                    "sugg 3"
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "ques": "4",
            "resp": {
                "ans": "nhcvuchaoiuoaiu",
                "syn": [
                    "sugg 1",
                    "sugg 2",
                    "sugg 3"
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I want to pass the parameter for ques.
If in postman I type question = 1, it must return resp on one

Answer (score 0):

Usually people use GET method to fetch resources. Below is the sample code that might help you.

```py
from flask import Flask, jsonify
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/questions')
def questions():
    return jsonify(Json)

@app.route('/questions/<qid>')
def question_details():
    question_data = {}
    for question in Json['array']:
        if question['ques'] == qid:
            question_data = question
    return jsonify(question_data)

if __nam__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: can i do it with post method?

Comment: You can, but why you want to do it post method? It not recommended to use POST to get the resources.